# Explain complex javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I got this code from somewhere on the internet but I don't quite understand it. Especially the `for` loop part.

```js
function FindPosition(oElement) {
  if( typeof( oElement.offsetParent ) != "undefined" ) {
    for( var posX = 0, posY = 0; oElement; oElement = oElement.offsetParent ) {
      posX += oElement.offsetLeft;
      posY += oElement.offsetTop;
    }
    return [ posX, posY ];
  }
  else {
    return [ oElement.x, oElement.y ];
  }
}
```

I don't understand particularly the `for` loop part here:

`for( var posX = 0, posY = 0; oElement; oElement = oElement.offsetParent )`

I expected there to be a middle expression or upper bound instead of just `oElement`

Please can someone explain to me?

Comment: `oElement` in the middle part is truthy while element exists. It traverses up through its parents until it gets to the root element, `oElement` becomes `null` which is falsy.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev sounds like this code could be written using a while loop, which could make the code easier to reason about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an example of using `for-loop` instead of `do-while`. If you rewrite this using do-while the overall idea behind the loop should be clear.

```
function FindPosition(oElement) {
  if( typeof( oElement.offsetParent ) != "undefined" ) {
    var posX = 0, posY = 0;
    do {
      // update coordinates using offset data
      posX += oElement.offsetLeft; 
      posY += oElement.offsetTop;

      // move up the DOM tree
      oElement = oElement.offsetParent

    } while(oElement != null) // while there is offsetParent

    return [ posX, posY ];
  }
  else {
    return [ oElement.x, oElement.y ];
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for the explanation. Please I am also not clear about `[ oElement.x, oElement.y ]`. Does this mean that html elements have `x` and `y` coordinates?

Comment: @Awa Never heard of it. Where did you get this code from?

Comment: from [here](http://www.chestysoft.com/imagefile/javascript/get-coordinates.asp) @YuryTarabanko

Comment: Not sure. This code might be written to take care of some non-standard browsers.  But I have never heard of it.

Answer (score 3):

A for loop header has 3 parts: initialization, condition, iteration.

Here, the condition (`...; oElement; ...`) is not in the form of a comparison against an upper bound (e.g. `i < 100`). Instead, it checks if oElement is true (i.e. not null, not undefined, not 0)

The iteration part(`...; oElement = oElement.offsetParent`) does not increase any indexing value as you are used to (e.g. `i++`). Instead, it moves upward in the element hierarchy by assigning oElement's parent to oElement.

The condition makes sure the upward traversal stops when there is no longer an offsetParent defined.